# Why is this c linked list deletion at head program not printing the desired output?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```c
// c program to delete first node..
// input size:3
// input elements:1,2,3
// desired output:2->3->NULL
// actual output:1->NULL

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void create(struct node *p)
{
    int x;
    
    printf("Enter the element :");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    
    struct node *nn = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nn->data = x;
    
    if (p->next==NULL){
        nn->next = p->next;
        p->next = nn;
    }
    else {
        while(p->next!=NULL){
            p = p->next;
        }
        nn->next = p->next;
        p->next =nn;
    }
}

void FirstNodeDeletion(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf(" There are no node in the list.");
    }
    else {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        printf("\n Data of node 1 which is being deleted is :  %d\n", temp->data);
        free(temp);  
    }
}

int search(struct node *pp,int data)
{
    struct node *p = pp;
    
    while(p->next!=NULL){
        if (p->data ==data){
            return 1;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void display(struct node *ptr)
{
    while (ptr->next!=NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("%d->",ptr->data);
    }
    
    printf("NULL");
}

int main() {
    
    struct node *head;
    
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next=NULL;
    
    int n,i;
    
    printf("Enter the size :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        create(head);
    }
    
    display(head);
    FirstNodeDeletion(head);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C != C++. Please only tag one next time. Also: please don't put white lines at every coffee line. And please write a clear question, don't just post some code.

Comment: Note: I simply applied correct code markdown; I did not go throuhg your code and check/fix issues with the code you posted like `malloc(size

of(struct node));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstNodeDeletion(head);` cannot change `head` because arguments are passed by value. You must rewrite `FirstNodeDeletion` to take a pointer to the head pointer and to use that pointer to get and to change `head`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is a bad approach when it is necessary to allocate the first node bypassing the corresponding function `create`. Moreover the function shall be able to deal with empty lists.

As for your problem then it can be resolved very simply by introducing one more structure as for example

```
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct list
{
    struct node *head;
};
```

In this case in main you could write

```
int main( void )
{
    struct list list = { .head = NULL };
    //...
```

and for example the function `FirstNodeDeletion` could look the following way

```
int FirstNodeDeletion( struct list *list )
{
    int present = list->head != NULL;

    if ( present )
    {
        struct node *current = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free( current );
    }

    return present;
}
```

and the function is called like

```
FirstNodeDeletion( &list );
```

All other functions should be changed in a similar way.